# Error while using the autofilter condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have an sheet FC. With this Sheet, I always check for the column S, T and U.

The first case is.

I column S has "invalid", then I want the whole row to be hidden.

In addition if the column T and U both are filled, then also, I want the row to be hidden.

I executed the below code.

```
Sub fc()
Dim totalrows As Long
totalrows = Range("A5").End(xlDown).Row
  With Sheets("FC").Range("Z5:Z" & totalrows)
    sformula = "=AND(S5<>""Invalid"",OR(ISBLANK(T5),ISBLANK(U5)))"
    .AutoFilter 26, True
    .Formula = sformula
    .Value = .Value
  End With
End Sub
```

with this code, I have an additional column Z used as an helper column. So if the column S is invalid, also if both the columns T and 5 are not blank, then I state them as "True" in column Z.

The problem here is, in the first iteration, it shows the perfect result. (It filters true and just shows False). With second iteration, the whole data is hidden.

I have this function calling with a button. inorder to unfilter, I am using the below code.

```
Sub UnfilterColumn()

    With Worksheets("FC")
        If Not Worksheets("FC").AutoFilter Is Nothing Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FC").Range("A4").AutoFilter Field:=26
        End If
    End With


End Sub
```

The issue again is even after unsing the unfilter code, with the first press, I get the result and with second step, all my data are hidden and in the third press, I could see the result.

Could some one help me to solve this issue. I believe the problem is in my FC code.

Is there anyother way to execute my requirement  ? Any lead would be helpful

Comment: What is the intention behind `.Value = .Value`?

Comment: @DavidG  to hide the formula and give it as value

Comment: Try swapping `.AutoFilter 26, True` and `.Formula = sformula` (Formula first, filter second). Also, notice, you have a header.

Comment: @AntiDrondert it works :) You can post and I would mark it as answer. But I would like to know the reason behind swapping. could you explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
Sub fc()
    Dim totalrows As Long
    Dim FC as Worksheet: Set FC=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FC")
    totalrows = FC.Range("A" & FC.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    sformula = "=AND(S6<>""Invalid"",OR(ISBLANK(T6),ISBLANK(U6)))"
    FC.Range("Z6:Z" & totalrows).Formula = sformula
    With FC.Range("Z5:Z" & totalrows)
        .AutoFilter 26, True
        .Value=.Value2
    End With
End Sub
```

I assume you have a header in line 5.
You had to swap lines because before inputing formula cells have no value at all, after `.AutoFilter` they were, well, filtered (vbNullString, "", 0 etc. <> True).
You could see the correct result on second iteration because cells asquired value (became True) and since `.AutoFilter` simply changes filter criteria he RE-filtered the column and got the result you needed.

Comment: @could you please explain the reson behind swapping the lines. It would be helpful for me in future ´

Comment: Edited the answer, explanation below